# iSCSI Initiator: Targets Lost Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, iscsi

I rebooted my servers last night after do a routine cleaning. When they came back online I saw my network maps had not reconnected so I investigated. Opening the iSCSI initiator screen every action I take yields a similiar permutation of the following error:

> The GUID passed was not recognized as valid by a WMI data provider.

What do I do to fix this?

Example from Volumes and Devices:
[image: Example from Volumes and Devices]

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have tried removing the discovery portl and re-adding them but i get the same generic error. Other servers are still able to connect to the targets so the issue is isolated to my hyper-v machine (screenshot above).